# Could we obtain the following limit appearance?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definite-integrals, indeterminate-forms

The question looks maybe simple, but it is interesting.

Let us suppose that we have the following function with the stated features:

--$\,\,\,$   $F(x,a)$  was defined as below:

$$ \frac{{ } \int_0^\infty g(x,a) \, dx}{\int_0^\infty h(x,a) \, dx^*} =^* F(x,a) $$ 
.

--$\,\,\,$ $F(x,a)$ is a finite and continuous. Beside$\,\,\,$   $\int_0^\infty g(x,a_0)dx=\int_0^\infty h(x,a_0)dx=0$ $\,\,\,$ at$\,\,\,$ $a_0$ .

--$\,\,\,$  And we know for all $\,\,\,$  $u$ $\,\,\,$  by including of the neighborhood of the infinity    that:  $$\int_0^u h(x,a_0)dx≠0$$

.

THE QUESTION.Could we obtain the following limit appearance (because we know that$\,\,\,$  *"for all $\,\,\,$  $u$ $\,\,\,$  by including of the neighborhood of the infinity    that:$\,\,\,$  $\int_0^u h(x,a_0)dx≠0$*)
$$.$$

$$ \frac{\lim_{u \to \infty} \int_0^u g(x,a) \, dx}{\lim_{u \to \infty}\int_0^u h(x,a) \, dx^*}=^* F(x,a) \,\,\  ⇒ \,\,\ \lim_{u \to \infty}  \frac{\int_0^u g(x,a_0) \, dx}{\int_0^u h(x,a_0) \, dx}=F(x,a_0) $$

Comment: What does the "*" mean in the definition of F?

Comment: @martycohen,  "*"  means that we are accepting naturally that the denominator are not equal to zero on this definition –